# Imitating a browser (with cookies) in python requests

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests, session-cookies

I'm trying to get the search results HTML of a website with python-requests. But I'm only getting back an HTML saying: "Checking your browser, please wait for 5s while we redirect you".

[image: HTML result]

I'm already sending in headers to imitate a browser:

```
res = rq.get(url, params = params, headers = headers)
```

Is there something I should be doing like sending in a cookie along with the GET request to make the website believe that it's just some regular user on a browser?

Comment: The site might be using a meta refresh tag (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/meta-refresh/) for redirect, or with JS (`window.location = "https://url"`). Can you share the url?

Comment: https://genius.com/search?q=any_song_name

Comment: That page loads song matches using JS. You should send a request to Genius API instead of scraping the page. See: https://genius.com/api/search/multi?per_page=5&q=hello

Comment: I know the api is always a choice, I wanted to know if a browser can be imitated and results scraped manually for educational purposes, there are even python packages that can get lyrics for you by using custom google site searches

Comment: In this case, it's not a choice, because there's nothing in HTML about song matches that you can scrape. They're all loaded afterwards.

Comment: Isn't there a way to simulate a browser and make the js load using some other python library. It's not efficient but just curious to know

Comment: To have the JS run properly (as whoever wrote that code intended to), you need a browser. In that case, take a look at Selenium, which lets you automate browser actions (and also run JS).

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the `If-None-Match:` header in your params. This will tell the server to redirect you to a cache instead, so you have to remove it.

Without any params it would work:

```
import requests
result = requests.get('https://genius.com/search?q=any_song_name', allow_redirects=False)
print(result)
```